# Suppose that $\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e. and that $|| f_n ||_p$ are uniformly bounded. Does $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e. and that $|| f_n ||_p$ are uniformly bounded. Does $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$?

I know that if the sequence of norms converges, then this is true. By Fatau's lemma, $f \in L^p$. Here I'm not making any assumptions on the measure, i.e. it could be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: On $\mathbb R$ consider $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}.$